# Add line-break in text/plain email

Tags: php

I'm using the function of WordPress `wp_mail()` to send an email about the form data that is submitted on my website.

In the `$data`, I have tried to use `\n` for line break but it printed \n on the email like below:

`First value \n Second value \n Third Value`

My code is:

`$data = "First: $first_value" . '\n' . "Second: $second_value" . '\n' . "Third: $third_value"`

The desired result in the email received is:

First: value

Second: value

Third: value

Comment: You need to put control characters (like `\n`) inside double quotes, or they will be read as ordinary text. Read more in the [PHP manual about strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/DRj4g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the break lines ("\n") are implemented appropriately, as M.Eriksson suggested, you must avoid single quatations when defining them. To be more clear, see the output of the code below:

```php
$first_value = "one";
$second_value = "second";
$third_value = "third";
$data = "First: $first_value" . '\n' . "Second: $second_value" . '\n' . "Third: $third_value";
echo($data);
```

```
First: one\nSecond: second\nThird: third
```

But when you use double quotation (") instead of single quotation (') the result would be:

```
<?php
$first_value = "one";
$second_value = "second";
$third_value = "third";
$data = "First: $first_value" . "\n" . "Second: $second_value" . "\n" . "Third: $third_value";
echo($data);
?>
```

```
First: one
Second: second
Third: third
```

A more generic approach would be using `PHP_EOL`:

```
<?php
$first_value = "one";
$second_value = "second";
$third_value = "third";
$data = "First: $first_value" . PHP_EOL . "Second: $second_value" . PHP_EOL . "Third: $third_value";
echo($data);
?>
```

```
First: one
Second: second
Third: third
```